# Google Chrome Custom URI-Scheme redirection to JS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, url-scheme, google-nativeclient

I am currently working on a custom uri-scheme (protocol) in google chrome and require a method to automate some testing (and development) of this protocol purely from within the chrome browser.

For example.  If a redirect/anchor link points to this example uri

```
testuri://thismessage/additionaldata
```

then I would like to to redirected back into JS somehow.  I.e. with a call to say

```
function protocolMessage(data) { ... }
```

I have explored the use of 'navigator.registerProtocolHandler' but that requires the use of 'web+testuri', which isn't an option (unless someone knows of a setting that can be used to turn this off).

I have investigated using a chrome custom extension to capture the uri under webNavigation but it doesn't capture anything but http(s) schemes.  And I cannot see any functions that would allow me to register a custom scheme directly either.

Further investigation led me to try calling out to a system application (using custom uri-schemes that call native executables) and this partly works but now i'm stuck on how to redirect that message back into the current page/tab's javascript.

I also had a look at NaCL (Pepper API's) but that doesn't seem to allow registration of custom schemes either.

I am hoping for a better solution than calling out and back into the browser, but if not can anyone shed any light on a good solid reusable solution?

Any ideas?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, no, sadly.

All Chrome APIs work with "supported schemes" and you can't add one.

`web+custom:` is also an inflexible limitation.

If you have a system application, you can talk to it by either providing a WebSocket server in the application, or working with Native Messaging.

The problem with native messaging is that Chrome has to initiate the connection to a new instance of the Native host. So you'll need to be able to handle the native app being invoked separately for protocol handling and for messaging.

Comment: That was what I was afraid of,  thank you for your help.  So it looks like the only way is to create a 3rd party app that the webpage will need to connect to.  Although your suggestion for using WebSockets is an idea that would be better than creating an extension.

Comment: It may be worth asking this as a feature request. I did a brief overview of the bugtracker, there's a [very old request](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=75015) regarding this in extensions. I say it's worth to take another look, even if they only implement it for Chrome Apps (which is likely).